# How to install cordova plugin in android studio and develop android projects?

Tags: android, cordova

I have downloaded phonegap 2.9.0. I have configured this plugin in android studio as per this link   http://www.thedevline.com/2014/03/how-to-build-phonegap-project-with.html .But I'm getting the error of 'cannot resolve symbol' while importing this packages
import org.apache.cordova.*;
Is this a plugin installation problem ? Can anybody help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't use phonegap 2.9.0, it's too old. As far as I know, there is no cordova plugin for android studio, work with the cordova CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES it's old Version. try to Installed With New One.

After Installed Just Add the line in your MainActivity.java file.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {}
```

I suggest first you build you PhoneGap project with Cordova CLI after completed creating project then finally import into android studio